# Sequences - Comparison Test

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following infinite series. What is the last step in determining whether it converges or diverges using the comparison test?

$$\dfrac{|\sin n|}{n^2+1}$$

I have got to

$$\dfrac{|\sin n|}{n^2+1}\leq   \dfrac{1}{n^2 + 1}$$

Let me know if I'm on the right track. I'm not sure how to finish the question off.

Thanks

Comment: you are on the right track! Last thing to show : $ 1/((n^2 + 1))$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Does the series of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converge? then using this can you conclude if the series with $\frac{1}{n^2 + 1}$ converges or diverges using the comparison test, with this you should be in a good situation to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you can show that $\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$ converges, then you can say that $\dfrac{|\sin n|}{n^2+1}$ converges as well.

Try testing the convergence of $\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$ by using $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$.